# How to change woocommerce search location?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce on my Wordpress site. My homepage only has one category so the search would only search in that category (client wants the homepage to only have one category). Whenever I try to search for something from a different category, it simply says that product is nonexistent.

How can I change the location where it should search so I can make another page with all the products?

Answer (score 0):

To alter the search query for only the home page to display products from a specific category, use the [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook

```
function include_category( $query ) {

    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        $query->set('tax_query', array(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array("**term name here**") )  // replace **term name here** with the slug of the term you wish to show on the home page
        ));     

    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'include_category' );
```

Depending whether you've set a static page or latest blog posts page as your home page you'll need to change `$query->is_home()` with `$query->is_front_page()`

Comment: I added this to my functions.php and changed the "**term name here**" with two other categories (one doesn't work either), but it still will only search in one category and not all of them. My homepage only shows one category and I want it to keep it that way, but the search should search all the categories (it only searches the category in the frontpage now).